# StrongSwan ikev2 routing through VPN in Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, strongswan, ikev2

I'm trying to create an ikev2 VPN using StrongSwan on an ubuntu server.

Now, in Windows 10 clients, `use default gateway on remote network` option is off by default; so when I connect to the server, traffic bypasses VPN completely unless I enable that option manually.

However, Windows 10 Mobile doesn't have that option.

On [StrongSwan website](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Windows7#Split-routing-on-Windows-10-and-Windows-10-Mobile), there's a paragraph about this issue and how to solve it:

> Microsoft changed Windows 10 Desktop and Mobile VPN routing behavior
>   for new VPN connections. Option "Use default gateway on remote network
>   option" in the Advanced TCP/IP settings of the VPN connection is now 
>   disabled by default. You can enable this option on Desktop but there
>   is no way to do this on Mobile. Fortunately, Windows sends DHCP
>   request upon connection and add routes supplied in option 249 of DHCP
>   reply.

(And then a sample dnsmasq configuration file)

But it's unclear about how should I configure StrongSwan that way, and I couldn't find any good resources clarifying this.

So the question is, how can I configure StrongSwan in a way that tells Windows 10 to move whole internet traffic (ipv4) through VPN?

Here's my `ipsec.conf`:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

config setup
    uniqueids=never
    charondebug="cfg 2, dmn 2, ike 2, net 2"

conn %default
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096,aes256-sha256-modp4096,aes256-sha1-modp4096,aes128-sha256-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes256-sha384-modp1536,aes256-sha256-modp1536,aes256-sha1-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes128gcm16-ecp256,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096,aes256-sha256-modp4096,aes256-sha1-modp4096,aes128-sha256-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes256-sha384-modp1536,aes256-sha256-modp1536,aes256-sha1-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128gcm16,aes256gcm16,aes128-sha256,aes128-sha1,aes256-sha384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1!
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    leftcert=vpnHostCert.pem
    right=%any
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsourceip=172.16.16.0/24

conn IPSec-IKEv2
    keyexchange=ikev2
    auto=add

conn IPSec-IKEv2-EAP
    also="IPSec-IKEv2"
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%any

conn CiscoIPSec
    keyexchange=ikev1
    # forceencaps=yes
    rightauth=pubkey
    rightauth2=xauth
    auto=add
```

Answer (score 0):

if you install dnsmasq and put this in the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
dhcp-vendorclass=set:msipsec,MSFT 5.0
dhcp-range=tag:msipsec,172.16.16.0,static
dhcp-option=tag:msipsec,6
dhcp-option=tag:msipsec,249, 0.0.0.0/1,0.0.0.0, 128.0.0.0/1,0.0.0.0
```

it adds two static routes on windows clients. The routes are `0.0.0.0/1` witch is the first half of the ipv4 address range and `128.0.0.0/1` witch is the second half.

For some reason you can't just do `0.0.0.0/0` but you have to divide it into two ranges.
I'm assuming windows ignores `/0` because static routes are not meant to act as a default gateway